# How do I make cron use UTC?

Tags: linux, cron, timezone

My local time zone is not UTC; How do I make cron use UTC for it's schedule without changing time zone on the computer in other aspects?

Comment: It might be possible to run the whole cron daemon under a different timezone setting. But doing that would depend on your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the timezone with the `TZ` environment variable. If your system is based on `systemd`, you thus may alter the `cron.service` file an set the variable for the service only.

E.g. for Debian in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/cron.service` add

```
Environment="TZ=UTC"
```

in the `[Service]`-section **after** `EnvironmentFile=` has been read (in order to ensure said file does not reset the value). Reload daemon and restart `cron.service`.

Tested on Debian 11.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible in [the `cronie` implementation](https://github.com/cronie-crond/cronie) of `cron`.

Per [`man cron`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html):

> It is possible to use different time zones for crontables.  See crontab(5) for more information.

Per [`man 5 crontab`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html),

> The  CRON_TZ  variable  specifies the time zone specific for the cron table.  The user should enter a time according to the specified time zone into the table.  The time used for writing into a log file is taken from the local time zone, where the daemon is running.

If you want to specify a timezone for your whole cron file, you can set a timezone as `CRON_TZ=UTC`, or any other timezone listed by  `timedatectl list-timezones`. This will run the command at the `UTC` time, but times used in the command will use your standard timezone.

If you want to reference the time in the command, you need to prefix the command/script with `/usr/bin/env TZ=UTC`